# c++ map with same key type and different item type

Tags: c++, stl, types, dictionary, key

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do you make a heterogeneous boost::map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251403/how-do-you-make-a-heterogeneous-boostmap)

It's possible have a map in C + + with the same type for the key and different types of items?
For example:

```
 _______________________
 |    key    |   value   |
 |===========|===========|
 | string    |   int     |
 |-----------|-----------|
 | string    |   char    |
 |-----------|-----------|
 | string    |  vector   |
 |-----------|-----------|
 | string    |   ....    |
```

Comment: How would you know what type of value your key referred to?  You probably could do something with a bunch of casting and using voids, but it seems like a *bad* idea...

Comment: ASked and answered: http://stackoverflow.com/q/251403/14065

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, store a variadic type, such as `boost::any` or (my personal preference, `boost::variant`)

So your value type can be defined as:

```
typedef boost::variant<int, char, ...> value_type;
```

Store than in the `map`, and then once you've extracted values, use the visitor concept to process.

Comment: In fact, in this case the map values all have the same type - `value_type`.

Comment: @unapersson: yes, but it does solve the issue the OP had :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure quite why you would want to do this, but you could use a `map<std::string, boost::any>` I believe.

What are you *really* trying to do?