# Vector that can hold any POD

Tags: c++, vector, c++11

Is there a sort of vector that can hold any POD? something like:

```
anyvector v;
v.push_back<int>(1);
v.push_back<somestruct>({1, 2, 3});
```

and access it with:

```
int a = v.get<int>(0);
somestruct b = v.get<somestruct>(1);
```

I know there must be an overhead to save the offsets of each element, but it should be less than the overhead of `vector<boost::any>` which is my current solution.
The operations I need is insertion to end, removal from end and random access.
I know its not a problem to implement one, just asking if there is a ready one.

Edit: A solution that uses pointers to store data (`boost::any`, `boost::variant`) is a big overhead over using linear storage which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Drop your attention to BOOST's [Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/any.html) and [Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/variant.html)

Comment: @megabyte1024: as I said, its my current solution, but each one carries a pointer which is a huge overhead against linear storage.

Comment: Or QVariant if you're using Qt.  Concentrate on making an Any-Type-Variable first (Any, Variant, QVariant), then putting this in a vector is then simply using std::vector on that type.

Comment: @Patrick: again, the problem is that it uses pointers and non linear storage

Comment: Can you use a different programming language? It seems as though you're [Greenspunning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun's_tenth_rule) (c:

Comment: @Dani: pointer solutions may carry a performance overhead during insertion, but linear storage either has a big memory overhead (with maximum size) or a non-constant complexity during access (with bookkeeping of offsets.

Comment: @steaanv: what you say is false. Consider an array of bytes containing the different-sized structures laid end-to-end, plus an array of `size_t` containing the offset of each element in turn. This doesn't have a "big" memory overhead associated with any maximum size, the overhead is one offset per element. It does have constant complexity during access, it's an `O(1)` double-indirection. Insert at the end is amortized `O(size of the new element)`, and remove at the end is `O(1)`. I think Dani knows this can be done, and knows how to do it, the question asks whether there's one prêt-à-porter.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/251403/14065

Comment: @SteveJessop: agreed, I should have thought at least 1 step further.  I thought of bookkeeping with a list of sizes of entries, but a list of offsets (as I actually wrote in my comment) makes more sense as you describe.  And no, I don't know any implementations and I will try not to need them either...

Comment: boost::variant does not use dynamic memory. It uses "linear" allocation.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::vector<boost::variant<int,somestruct,...>> v;

v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(({1, 2, 3});

a = boost::get<int>(v[0]);
```

provided you know which types have to be handled at declaration.

-- edit

As JohannesD said `boost::variant` impacts the size of each element, but
as James Kanze said, maintaining a vector of offset is very similar to `boost::any` and I am not sure you can really be more compact.

Depending on your exact requirement, another solution may work for you.
Store internally a different container for each type, this may not be a lot better than directly using multiple vectors, but you can store extra information like the last few elements stored. and you still got everything in one place.
Something like :

```
template <template <class,class> class C, typename T, typename ...Args>
struct map_ { //FIXME: return a list of type C<T1>,C<T2>...
};

template <template <class...> class C, typename ...Args>
struct fill_ { // Hack to parametrize map by Args on GCC 4.6
 typedef T<Args> type;
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct hvec
{
 std::map<std::string,fill_<boost::variant,map_<std::vector,Ts>> vec_map;
 std::size_t last_id;
 std::string last_typeid;

 template <typename T>
 T get(std::size_t i)
 {
   std::vector<T>& v = vec_map[typeid(T).name];
   return vec[i];
 }

 template <typename T>
 std::size_t push_back(const T& e)
 {
   std::vector<T>& v = vec_map[typeid(T).name];
   v.push_back(e);
 }
};
```

Of course you could replace vectors by maps and thus remember elements id, this would fulfill your requirement but add extra costs and still implies one "address"/key by element. However in this case you will never have to remember the type of an element at a given offset.

Comment: as I said, its like my current solution (boost:any), but each one carries a pointer which is a huge overhead against linear storage.

Comment: @Dani You are going to incur this overhead no matter what, see Steve’s answer. I don’t think a different solution can be fundamentally more efficient than either `boost::any` or `boost::variant`.

Comment: @Konrad: my answer was actually wrong. I focussed on "a sort of vector", when I should have focussed on the actual required operations. Random access incurs overhead, but you have two options. You could allocate the data outside the vector and have fixed-size pointers to it (like boost::any), or you could put the elements end-to-end in a big array and hold a separate array mapping index to offset in the data. The latter might be less overhead than separate allocation, relying on the fact that removal is only at the end, which a normal memory allocator can't assume.

Comment: @Dani - `boost::variant` is stack-based (but your point stands, of course - a `variant<T...>` always uses `max(sizeof(T)...)` bytes, independent of what it contains.)

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of one, and I'd be surprised if one exists, given how
very special it is.  It shouldn't be too hard to implement, however,
using two vectors, a `std::vector<unsigned char>` for the raw memory
where you put the objects, and `std::vector<size_t>` to map the indexes.
As long as it only contains POD's, you can use `memcpy` to insert the
elements.  Just don't forget to respect alignment.  And that the index
array maps indexes: don't try to put pointers into it, since these will
be invalidated by later `push_back`.

For that matter, it shouldn't be too hard to implement one which holds
any type, even non-PODs, using placement new and explicit destruction.
The only real problem would be alignment.  When you insert into the
vector, you'ld have to also save an instance of a polymorphic destructor
type.  This could be a little tricky, but is doable, at least in
practice.  Basically, you'ld be duplicating what `boost::any` does, but
instead of the pointer to dynamic memory, you'd get the "dynamic memory"
from the second array.

Comment: The main issue I'd expect is the need to call destructirs, whethet for PODs or not: objects created need to be destroyed although it is often not done for PODs. When getting this right I'd think you effectively have implemented `std::vector<boost::any, pool_allocator>`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl **IF** you can guarantee that the objects have trivial destructors (which is a big if, IMHO), then you can skip the destructors.  More to the point: the allocator used by the `vector` isn't the issue; what you're implementing is an equivalent of `boost::any` which uses your allocator: basically, you have a vector of your `any`, in which your `any` uses a vector of `unsigned char` as it's memory source, rather than the standard `new`.  (Of course, it would have to maintain its "pointer" as a `size_t`, to avoid invalidation when the vector grew.)

Answer (score 0):

So you don't want pointers: that means you need an element type big enough to directly contain any POD. Given that POD objects can have arbitrary size, this is obviously impossible.

If you have a set of candidate types, it seems like you can have a bounded-size discriminated union, but isn't that what Boost.Variant does? The documentation indicates it will be stack-based (so presumably inline) where possible. How did you measure this "big overhead"?

Comment: I don't want a union, I want a vector that can contain arbitrary sized elements

Comment: If the element size is not fixed, this container will not perform like, or in any meaningful sense _be_, either a vector or an array. How would it ever calculate the offset for an index?

Comment: I think he wants O(n) lookup time. Or maybe O(n) extra memory to store the offsets.

Comment: So not, in fact, a vector :-)

Comment: @Useless Not something that fills the standard's requirements for `std::vector`, no. The concepts of storage and runtime don't have anything to do with the abstract mathematical concept of a vector, so they shouldn't change anything in that regard.

Comment: @bames53: ??? In the mathematical theory, a vector is a data structure from which we may do calculations on the complexity of operations.  This is clearly asking for something with different mathematical properties.

Comment: @ex0du5 No, an abstract mathematical vector is not a data structure in the CS sense, nor do operations on it such as 'retrieve the _i_ th element' have any defined complexity. You can compute the complexity of some operations in terms of others though (e.g., adding two vectors of size N is O(2N retrievals + N element additions). If we say that retrieving an element is O(N) and element addition is O(1) then this is O(N^2)).

Comment: @bames53: The vector from point geometry (which appears to be what you are referring) has nothing to do with what anyone else is talking about, nor does it in anyway answer the question.  Those vectors are bound mappings from a space to a cartesian product, they have well-defined types (they are function types), and given a basis to the space, they produce a value in a cartesian product.  There is no such thing as a heterogeneous vector in point geometry.  I am not sure why you went that direction.

Comment: @ex0du5 Useless said 'not, in fact, a vector' and I was trying to figure out what sort of vector he was talking about and why an implementation with either O(n) extra storage or O(n) lookup would not "in any meaningful sense _be_ [...] a vector [...]." I ruled out the possibility that he was talking about `std::vector` (the statement would be too obvious) or the abstract concept of a vector (the statement would not be true). I still haven't determined what he was referring to. (and by 'abstract concept of a vector' I didn't just mean vectors from point geometry. Vectors can be heterogeneous.)

Comment: Well this is tagged `C++`, so yes, I would tend to relate any use of the term _vector_ to `std::vector` unless the context indicated otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

you could try soemthing like the combination of vector and pair

```
enum ElementType : unsigned int
{
  ET_INT,
  ET_WHATEVER
};

vector < pair < void*, unsigned int >* > v;
pair < void*, unsigned int > prv;
int i;

prv.first = &i;
prv.second = ET_INT;

v.push_back( &prv );
```

it would be your choice to store objects by reference or by value. access to singloe elements would be like that:

```
int a = *( int* ) v.at( 0 )->first
```

that would give you fixed vector element size and info on the type of every stored element. when storing objects by reference watch out for lifetimes and namespaces, but i prefer conversion from types and making sure that the void pointers are valid instead of passing hugh sized parameters to functions everytime.

hope it helps;)

Answer (score 0):

A std::tuple can store a sequence of arbitrarily sized elements, but only a fixed set of them.

An arbitrary number of elements with arbitrary types at runtime sounds error prone and very unsafe. What do you expect to happen if you do the following?

```
anyvector v;
v.push_back<Foo>(Foo());
int i = v.back<int>();
```

You'd be lucky if the implementation could provide you with a runtime exception, and I don't think there's any way that an implementation of anyvector could guarantee that. For example, if it tried to use RTTI it would run into the problem that there's actually no guarantee that two type_info objects that refer to different types won't be equal.

Answer (score 0):

I think to get the best approximation to what you want, you will need to build your own data structure.  You can base your type off of two implementation types:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> blobStorage_;
std::vector<size_t> offsetMap_;
```

This is effectively a serialisation blob implementation with the ability to offset access individual objects serialised into the blob.

When you want to push_back an object, you

1. serialise it into the end of the blobStorage
2. add the offset (front of your new object's blob) into the offsetMap

Similarly when you want access element that you think of as vector[n], you

1. get the offset from offsetMap_[n]
2. deserialise the object as the supplied type from blobStorage_[offset]

Both of these operations are order O(sizeof(object)), but effectively constant.

Usually, though, when you want to do something like this, you do "actual" serialisation into a blob, where by "actual" I mean you actually design the serialisation into your program.  This typically means that you use a standard header to the storage of your types that gives a type ID and potentially size information.  The reason you would normally do this is because you lose the type information when you serialise, and in the usage pattern you have indicated (where the type is supplied in the get), you are building a very fragile program with a lot of unwritten contracts.  You don't typically want your programs easy to break in a professional environment working with others.  So you can make it much more robust by storing type ids and registering the types with their type ids inside a greater serialisation design.  Then, the "vector" will know how to deserialise and present the correct type of object.

Answer (score 0):

- `std::vector` stores elements as a contiguous array
- In such an array each element has a starting address `sizeof(Elem)` past the previous element
- POD types may be arbitrarily large
- There is no way to have a vector of arbitrarily large objects, because `sizeof(Elem)` is unlimited.

The answer, unless you can restrict yourself further, is simply no.

If you can set an upper size limit, then yes it is possible, without any overhead. POD objects can be used without explicit construction, or killed without explicit destruction. So you can just create a vector of `std::array< char, N >` and `reinterpret_cast` the elements to your desired type.

```
typedef std::vector< std::array< char, pod_size_max > > pod_variant_vector;

template< typename destination >
destination &get( pod_variant_vector &vec, std::size_t index )
    { return reinterpret_cast< destination & >( vec[ index ] ); }

template< typename destination >
destination const &get( pod_variant_vector const &vec, std::size_t index )
    { return reinterpret_cast< destination const & >( vec[ index ] ); }
```

Be sure not to use the value of any such object before it has been initialized using the same type you are `get`ting.