# C++ Map with template with different types

Tags: c++, templates, containers

I am using Google Protobuf and I want to use the created classes in a 'base' class. I created a template for this, but I want to add references to other classes within it (which can be a reference to 1 class, or more classes). Example:

```
template<typename T>
class SomeClass
{
    public:
        std::shared_ptr<T> get(int id)
        {
            // Of course this contains more checks, but that is not important for the example.
            items.find(id).second();
        }

        void add (std::shared_ptr<T> item)
        {
            items.emplace(item.id(), item)
        }

    private: 
        std::map<int, T> items;
}
```

This works ok. But now I want to add a map or vector or whtvr with SomeClass items in it, but the T here is different every time. So I want to be able to do:

```
SomeClass<Person> person;
SomeClass<Animal> animal;
SomeClass<Plant> plant;
person.add(animal);
person.add(plant);
```

The add function should look something like this:

```
private: 
    std::vector<SomeClass<???>> someContainer;

public:
    void add(SomeClass<???> item)
    {
        someContainer.push_back(item);
    }
```

Maybe good to know: T is a google protobuf Message.

I tried to add a class where SomeClass derives from. However, when you want to do the 'get', you need to have T as well for the base class. And then it starts over again.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `However, when you want to do the 'get', you need to have T as well for the base class.` That problem won't go away. If I say `person.get(...)` what type would the return value have? You may be interested in [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant), but you need to figure out how this class should be used (`person.get<int>(...)`?) and how both you and the compiler can know what type `get` should return before thinking about the implementation. You might also find inspiration by looking for "C++ heterogeneous container" in your favorite search engine.

Comment: In particular: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.advanced, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251403/how-do-you-make-a-heterogeneous-boostmap, https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/containers#heterogeneous-containers

Comment: Person does actually know about Animal and Plant, because it has member variables of this types. It would also be ok to add a shared pointer of these members to SomeClass. However, I don't know this on beforehand for all template parameters, some have 1 or more classes as members, some have none.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and pointing me in a search direction. Next thing is I will try to make it work with boost::any and/or boost::variant. I hope that will do the trick. I know the types, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: Or maybe a combination of variadic templates and tuple. Hmm...